# Find only numbers in list

Tags: prolog

I need to write a rule, what finds only numbers in list M and outputs only the numbers in list O.

Query looks like: `find(M, O)`

I can't figure it out on my own and hope someone can help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We like to help people who first help themselves :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "classical Prolog" way to do it:

```
find([], []).
find([H|T], [H|NewT]) :-
    number(H),
    find(T, NewT).
find([H|T], NewT) :-
    \+ number(H),
    find(T, NewT).
```

There are 3 clauses.

1st says that for an empty list the result is an empty list.

2nd says: if the first element (head, `H`) of the input list is a number, keep it in the output, and the rest of the output (new tail, `NewT`) is `find` applied to the rest of the input list (tail, `T`).

3rd clause is structurally similar to the second, but says not to keep head if it's not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach, using `findall/3` which is available in most Prolog implementations. But for a beginner, Sergey's answer is arguably best for beginners to learn how basic recursive list processing works.

```
find(M, O) :-
    findall(X, (member(X, M), number(X)), O).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using swi-prolog, you'll be happy to use the [`include/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) predicate as so:

```
find_numbers(M,O) :-
    include(number,M,O).
```