# How to count only the number elements in a list (PROLOG)

Tags: prolog

```
count([],0).
count([_|Tail], N) :- count(Tail, N1), N is N1 + 1.
```

This count all the elements, but I need to count only the numbers.

Comment: With a little searching on SO, you could find [Find Only Numbers In List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618589/find-only-numbers-in-list)

Comment: @coder: That's not a duplicate!!

Comment: @coder: There is just too much difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prolog has an ISO builtin predicate [**`number/1`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number/1) that checks whether the given parameter is a number.

We can simply use an if-then-else statement that either increments `N is N1+1`, or sets `N = N1`, like:

```
count([],0).
count([H|Tail], N) :-
    count(Tail, N1),
    (  number(H)
    -> N is N1 + 1
    ;  N = N1
    ).
```

Comment: When I try ?- count([1,3,4,5,a,f,v], 0).
The answer is false, instead of the count of number elements

Comment: @AlexandreRocha: that is correct, the total count is not `0`, it is `4`... You should query `count([1,3,4,5,a,f,v], N).` or `count([1,3,4,5,a,f,v], 4).`.

Comment: Ohh... I see, THANK YOU VERY MUCH Wiillem , you really help me.

Comment: `count([X], 0))`. succeeds, but `X = 1, count([X], 0)` fails.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600104/772868) for a clean solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use `number/1` iso built-in predicate:

```
count([],0).
count([H|Tail], N) :- number(H),count(Tail, N1), N is N1 + 1.
count([H|Tail], N) :- \+number(H),count(Tail, N).
```

Comment: When I try ?- count([1,3,4,5,a,f,v], 0). The answer is false, instead of the count of number elements

Comment: Yes the answer that prolog gives you is right!!

Comment: `count([X], 0))`. succeeds, but `X = 1, count([X], 0)` fails.

Comment: @false I don't see anything wrong, `X = 1, count([X], 0) `clearly must fails and the only thought is what should `count([X], 0) ` do ?? (succeeding in last case is not that bad...)

Comment: For a relational solution (that is, a solution which maintains that the definition is a relation) you have at least two options: produce an instantiation error (as with [`number_itype/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600104/772868)), or use, say `number_type(N) :- freeze(N, number(N))` - but then you would need a `non_number_type(N) :- freeze(N, \+ number(N)).` too.

Comment: Another option might be that you loop in that case. Not the best option but better than producing an incorrect result.

Comment: @false ,thanks for the helpful comments !!